# Adding a footer to the first page

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am required to use a custom LaTeX class. This class internally uses `fancyhdr` and, no matter how much I try, I cannot add a footer to the first page. The footer can appear on other pages but not on the first page. Since I am not allowed to change the LaTeX class for this document, are there any other packages I can use to add a footer?

**Edit**

Unfortunately, I cannot provide any MWE because the Latex class is proprietary and not available in the public domain.

Comment: it is difficult to help if you show no code but probably your first page has a title command that does `\thispagestyle{empty}`  you can re-enable the page style with a later `\thispagestyle{fancy}` or whatever page style you are using

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately, I cannot provide any code as the Latex class is proprietary and not available in the public domain.

Comment: you could provide _some_ clues. Or if it is a commercially supported class, then ask the people supporting it. There really isn't a  lot anyone can do to a question that basically amounts to "some code I have not shown does something I do not expect, how do I fix it".

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You're right. It's rude of me to ask this question here

Comment: not rude, but possibly pointless, unless actually my first comment solves your problem (which probably it will if used with the right page style)

Comment: Your first comment did not solve the problem. But I appreciate a lot your patience and your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is just the first page of the document then something like this should work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{%
  \fancyhead{}
  \renewcommand\headrule{}
  \fancyfoot[C]{First page footer}
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{firstpage}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

If you want it for the first page of each chapter, then use

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{....}
```