# How can we add some text in the bottom margin of the first page?

Tags: marginnote

I want to know how can I add some text in the bottom margin of a document like the following picture?

[image]
I tried to do it, but it is appearing on all the pages. I want this to appear only in the first page. Thanks.

Comment: I think you are looking for the term `footer`. For example, have a look at the package `fancyhdr` (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fancyhdr). For more specific help, it would be beneficial if you provide an MWE, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228.

Comment: See https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5786 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/602281 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30228 for example.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to these links, but these were not the exact solution I was looking for. After digging a few more things, I found the most appropriate solution here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24663/how-to-place-a-floating-text-box-at-a-specified-location-in-page-coordinates.

Comment: I am happy to hear that you solved the problem. In the future please provide a bit more information about your problem including some code. Otherwise it leaves too much room for interpretation.

Answer (score 3):

In plain TeX, there is `\footline` tokens list used for the footer. You can do something like this:

```
\newtoks\footlinebak

\footlinebak=\footline
\footline={\hss This acrticle is accepted...\hss \global\footline=\footlinebak}

%test:
first page  
\vfil\break

second page 
\bye
```